# AccessDeniedException on macOS (Java)

Tags: java, macos, access-denied, create-directory

I try to create a directory but I constantly get the AccessDeniedException.
How can I get access?

code:

```
String pathForMac = System.getProperty("user.home") + "Library\\Application Support\\Petatech\\Zindroid";
Path macPath = Paths.get(pathForMac);{

if (!Files.exists(macPath)) {
    try {
        Files.createDirectory(macPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Privileged Block API to do that. Something like this should work as System.getProperty(String key) might be the one throwing the AccessDeniedException due to lack of permissions.

```
String pathForMac = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
    new java.security.PrivilegedAction<String>() {
        public String run() {
            return System.getProperty("user.home");
        }
    });
//Append the rest to the String
pathForMac += "Library\\Application Support\\Petatech\\Zindroid";
```

Comment: Actually, Paths.get(pathForMac), Files.exists(macPath), and Files.createDirectory(macPath) could throw SecurityException. Check the stack trace and wrap the corresponding statements in a doPrivileged block.